# jQuery not seeing string in span that's displayed with php echo

Tags: php, jquery, echo, getelementbyid, document-ready

My php page looks something like this (with jQuery loaded above the script). It works correctly (the css for #desc-* changes from display:none to display:inline) when the text within span id="description" is normal text, but when using php echo function (it's retrieving the string value for $itemdesc from the URL; the value can either be "Product A" or "Product B") to display the string, the code doesn't work. I thought the ready function would let the PHP / DOM load and it would work, but nope.

Edit: I removed the php short tag but that didn't help. (The echo function was working with or without the short tag).

Edit #2: I'm now using @Alex Andrei 's js code. But the issue seems to be due to using _GET (my knowledge here is limited). As a test, I replaced `<?php $itemdesc=$_GET["itemdesc"]; >` with `<?php $itemdesc = 'Product A';>`   and then echo'd it, and the javascript worked.

Edit 3: Solved. the strings weren't matching 100% because of white space characters.

```
<?php $itemdesc=$_GET["itemdesc"]; ?>  //can be "Product A" or "Product B"

<html>

<style>
 #desc-a, #desc-b {display: none;}
</style>

You purchased: <span id="description"><?php echo $itemdesc ?></span> and 
    <span id="desc-a">you'll get it in 1 day.</span>
    <span id="desc-b">you'll get it in 5 days.</span>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    var c = document.getElementById("description").innerHTML;

    if (document.getElementById("description").innerHTML == "Product A") {
        document.getElementById("desc-a").style.display = "inline";

    if (document.getElementById("description").innerHTML == "Product B") {
        document.getElementById("desc-b").style.display = "inline";
    }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you get an error message ? What's give console.log(c) ?

Comment: Are short tags enabled?

Comment: This doesn't make sense for a varietly of reasons. First off, what errors do you get? Do you have PHP short tags enabled? Also, if you're using jQuery, then *use* jQuery and don't do `document.getElementById("desc-b").style.display = "inline";`

Comment: 2 Notes - First, PHP is executed server side.  That means that the $itemdesc value is already part of the page when it loads.  Second, you are inserting a GET value directly into your page.  This is a security problem - a link could be generated to this page with malicious scripts inserted into it.  Please consider sanitizing the contents of any value you display in your page.

Comment: Also... your first if statement has no closing `}`.  To make your code more complete - in case your item description is neither Product A or B - you may want to add a default case to handle that.  Finally, since you know what your product is when you generate the page in PHP, why not set the other parts from php too?  The more you do on the server, the faster it runs and the less you have to deal with two different languages,

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the security issue. For the time being, my main problem seems to be something to with the _GET , because as a test, I removed it, and replaced it <?php $itemdesc = 'Product A'; ?> and then echo'd it, and the javascript worked...

Comment: Try inspecting the HTML in your browser so you can see exactly what  you're getting from $_GET["itemdesc"].  When you test the value of the product name, in PHP or JavaScript, the match needs to be 100% perfect.

Comment: Thank you @Surreal Dreams ! It was indeed an issue with white space characters. On the page it looked like 1 space, but inspecting the HTML, there were several white spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `jQuery` for this

See the below example

```
<?php

$itemdesc = trim($_GET["itemdesc"]);

?>

<script type="text/javascript">

var desc = document.getElementById("description");

switch(true){

  case desc.innerHTML == 'Product A':
    document.getElementById("desc-a").style.display = "inline";
    break;

  case desc.innerHTML == 'Product B':
    document.getElementById("desc-b").style.display = "inline";
    break;

}
</script>
```

Also your `if` blocks are not opened/closed properly.

UPDATE:
I added a `trim` around the `GET` to do away with any leading or trailing whitespace such as newlines or spaces.

You should definitely consider the approach @SurrealDreams proposed in his answer since it takes away a number of security issues.

Comment: DOM ready event is necessary unless script is at the end or after element.

Comment: Correct, but the script **is** at the end *or* after the element according to the question

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler way to approach this page:

```
<?php
$itemdesc=$_GET["itemdesc"];

if ($itemsdesc == "Product A") {
    $delay = "1 day"
} elseif ($itemsdesc == "Product B") {
    $delay = "5 days"
} else {
    $delay = "several days"
}
?>  

You purchased: <span id="description"><?php echo $itemdesc ?></span> and 
   you'll get it in <?php echo $delay ?>.
```

No JavaScript at all.  But please don't insert $_GET values directly into the page.  That leaves you page open to attack with a malicious link.

Comment: you could add a `trim` to the `$_GET`, the OP seems to have an issue with the `GET` value itself vs. hardcoding the string in `php`

Comment: @AlexAndrei - It could be any deviation at all from his expected values.  Trim may or may not help.  Could be case, a typo, unicode characters, whitespace, or other unexpected values just to start.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to make your script to work I found out that the short tags `<? ?>`

where not working but your javascript was working fine if you include jquery

of course.

So you either enable short tags `short_open_tag=On` in your php.ini

or use `<?php ?>`

Comment: How do you know short tags are not enabled on @Jake's server?

Comment: @SurrealDreams, you are right I don't but this was the problem that prevented his initial script from running in my server ( and a missing `}` in javascript)  so I imagine that was the case for his, but your question right

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var c = document.getElementById("description").innerHTML;

   if (c == "Product A") {
       document.getElementById("desc-a").style.display = "none";
   }  <---  //this was missing btw
   if (c == "Product B") {
      document.getElementById("desc-b").style.display = "inline";
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have a race condition. The innerHTML value may be rendered after document.ready is complete.

You could set an interval. I use the doTimeout jQuery plugin as an interval to check if c has any value. If not, run the check until there is value.

For example:

```
$.doTimeout( 100, function(){
  if ( $("#description" ).text() != "") {
    $("#description" ).text() == "Product A" ? $("#desc-a").css("display","inline") : $("#desc-b").css("display","inline");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
});
```

This interval runs every 100 ms. Once the condition returns true it executes the DOM manipulations.

Maybe not the most elegant way to go about it. Just a thought.